# How do I set cgroup limits for systemd user slices?

Tags: systemd, cgroup

I would like to limit usage of a system on a per user basis. Since Systemd has native support for cgroups, I think using user slices is the way to go.

The problem is: I can't figure out how to set individual limits. I can edit the user.slice unit file to set limits that collectively apply to all user slices, but I don't see a way to template these user slices.

I can override these settings for individual users by creating a user-(uid).slice unit file, but I would prefer to apply limits by default to all users.

Is it possible to set default limits?

**Edit**:
After poking around some more, I found the unit files for the user slices are created in /run/systemd/system/.

```
[foo@bar Downloads]$ systemctl cat user-1000.slice
# /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice
# Transient stub

# /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-After-systemd-logind\x2eservice.conf
[Unit]
After=systemd-logind.service
# /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-After-systemd-user-sessions\x2eservice.conf
[Unit]
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
# /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-Description.conf
[Unit]
Description=User Slice of foo
# /run/systemd/system/user-1000.slice.d/50-TasksMax.conf
[Slice]
TasksMax=infinity
```

These files are constructed by this segment of code in systemd: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/401e33ed56f3cd3736bbab02ca6eb31aa592cf53/src/login/logind-dbus.c#L2928-L2998

The creation of this file seems to be hard coded into the systemd source and doesn't allow for templates.

Comment: This remains [an open issue in systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2556).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for linking that issue. Looks like I have my answer, and that answer is "no", at least not with Systemd

Comment: systemd v239 closed the issue, apparently now you can create an dropin directory such as  "user-.slice.d".

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set

```
UserTasksMax=12299
```

After rebooting my machine I could see the above value set (1000 is my UID):

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max
12299
```

Extract form man logind.conf:

```
   UserTasksMax=
       Sets the maximum number of OS tasks each user may run concurrently. This controls the TasksMax= setting of the per-user slice unit, see systemd.resource-control(5) for details. Defaults to 12288
       (12K). If assigned the special value "infinity", no tasks limit is applied.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in **Ubuntu 18.04**:

1) Edit `/data/repos/mhservers/etc/pam.d/common-session` and add:

```
session  optional  pam_systemd.so
```

2) Edit `/etc/security/limits.d/somename.conf` and set

```
someuser  soft  nofile  1024000
someuser  hard  nofile  1024000
```

3) Lookup UID using `id -u someuser`

4) Execute `systemctl restart user@[UID].service`

To verify `someuser` can execute `systemctl --user show somesvr.service | grep NOFILE`